# Adding a custom page dynamically (at runtime)

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm writing an install script utilizing the NSIS installer scripting language.  I have a few custom pages that I am able to load without hassle, but I was wondering if it would be possible to insert pages dynamically.  What I want to do is have a page with additional configuration options on it and on the bottom have a checkbox that says "Add more settings" or something similar.  If the checkbox is ticked, it will show another custom page that's an exact copy of the first one.  As long as the user keeps checking the checkbox, more pages should be shown.  Is there some method of recycling the same page over and over again? I really don't think I should need to generate a whole new page because it's just the same page again and again, but I'm not sure how to show a new instance of the same page during runtime.  A quick Google and stackoverflow search did not warrant any results.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of pages is fixed at compile time.

If you need different "hidden" pages or just a couple instances of the same page I would say that you should just skip the pages when required in the create callback for the page by calling abort but this is not going to work if the page count is unlimited.

It is also possible to go directly to a page:

```
Outfile test.exe
Requestexecutionlevel user

!include nsDialogs.nsh

Page Custom mypagecreate mypageleave
Page Directory dirpagecreate
Page Instfiles

Function mypagecreate
Var /Global MyCheckBox
nsDialogs::Create /NOUNLOAD 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 10% 20u 80% 12u "Again?"
Pop $MyCheckBox
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function mypageleave
${NSD_GetState} $MyCheckBox $0
StrCpy $MyCheckBox $0 ; This is a bit of a hack, we reuse the HWND var to store the state
FunctionEnd

Function dirpagecreate
${If} $MyCheckBox <> 0 ; Was the checkbox checked?
    SendMessage $HWNDPARENT 0x408 -1 "" ; If so, go back
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: This looks really good to me.  I didn't think about storing the window handle to reuse at a later time.  I'll test this out and edit this to let you know whether or not it works as expected, but it looks good to me from this point.

Comment: That worked very well for me.  I was able to get everything working as I wanted.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
page custom page1 option
page instfiles

Function page1
initpluginsdir
file /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini dlg.ini
installoptions::dialog "$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini"
FunctionEnd

Function Options
ReadINIStr $0 "$PLUGINSDIR\dlg.ini" "Field 1" "State" # Field Must have value 0 or 1. Maybe Text or Chechbox
StrCmp $0 0 0 +2
abort
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but *fuller explanations* are better." *[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)*. Stack Overflow values full and complete answers. You can edit your answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692618/how-to-export-all-rows-from-datatables-using-ajax/57525604?noredirect=1#)** or click the "edit" button in the bottom left corner of your answer. Thanks.