# Export All from DataTables with Server Side processing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have tables which use DataTables Server Side processing to show on my website. I want to be able to 'Export All' and have all rows be exported, not just those rows being displayed. There are 60000+ rows and 65+ columns, so it must be done with server side processing.

I have tried a few things, but so far nothing has worked.

I have tried this:

```
{ extend: 'excel',
    text: 'Export Current Page',
    exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
            page: 'current'
        }
    },
    customize: function (xlsx)
    {
        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
    }
}
```

Which only exported the rows that were showing on the page.

I've tried this:

```
{
    text: 'Export All to Excel',
    action: function (e, dt, button, config)
    {
        dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data)
        {
            data.length = -1;
        }).one('draw', function (e, settings, json, xhr)
        {
            var excelButtonConfig = $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5;
            var addOptions = { exportOptions: { 'columns': ':all'} };

            $.extend(true, excelButtonConfig, addOptions);
            excelButtonConfig.action(e, dt, button, excelButtonConfig);
        }).draw();
    }
}
```

This sends the whole table's data to the screen instead of using the pagination and sending the whole data set to an excel file.

I've searched around on Google and here in SO, but have not found a solution that works.

I should also mention that I want to Export All based on the current filters set on the table. So that the end user will get an Export of only those rows that they are searching for. They typically limit it to 30k - 40k rows, still with the 65+ columns. I don't (yet) allow to remove/hide columns.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Here's a secondary consideration: If I can't Export All from a response from the server, can I build the Excel file on the server? My servers don't have Excel installed and I will still want my end user to get the file. I'm sure that I'd have to find a way to get Excel onto my servers, but how would I transfer any created files to the end user and would that even be any faster than just sending a response with the whole dataset and creating the Excel file on the user's computer?

**EDIT**

It was recommended that I try jquery's `$.ajax()` to get this to work. If someone could give me an idea of how to do that I'll try that for a third button.

I can already pull all the data, with the same filters and sorting that are added by the user, and do that with a button. The second attempt above does that but sends it to the screen. I have PHPExcel and a file that can create an Excel sheet. How would I take what I get in that second button and send it to the other file to create the Excel sheet? I thought that using jquery's `$.ajax()` might work, I just don't know how to get it to. I do know that I'll have to use `$_POST` since the data could be too big to use `$_GET` to send the data to the PHPExcel file.

I can already export to a CSV, but I need to export with some formatting, which CSV does not have. That's why I'm going to the trouble of use PHPExcel.

**EDIT III**

I am trying this, though it's not yet working:

```
{
    text: 'Export all to Excel II',
    action: function (e, dt, button, config)
    {
        dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data)
        {
            data.length = -1;
        }).one('export', function (e, settings, json, xhr)
        {
            var excelButtonConfig = $.fn.DataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5;
            var addOptions = { exportOptions: { 'columns': ':all'} };

            $.extend(true, excelButtonConfig, addOptions);
            excelButtonConfig.action(e, dt, button, excelButtonConfig);
        })
    }
}
```

**EDIT 4**

Hopefully the last edit.

I know that I have to do three things to make this work:

1. Get current Sorting and Filtering
2. Get dataset with length set to -1
3. Send this to PHPExcel file for processing and creation of Excel file
   I can create a button like this:

   {
       text: 'Export all Data to Excel',
       action:
   }

I just don't know what the action needs to be.

My second attempt above pulls the whole dataset that I need, but sends it to the screen instead of to my PHPExcel file (*ExportAllToExcel.php*).

I have been trying to figure this out and haven't gotten very far. I've been told that I need to use `$.ajax()` to do this, I've been told that I don't need to use that. I have tried with and without and have not been able to get anywhere.

I have also tried using this to no effect:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',
    "text": "Export All Test",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        var SearchData = dt.search();
        var OrderData = dt.order();
        alert("Test Data for Searching: " + SearchData);
        alert("Test Data for Ordering: " + OrderData);
    }
};
```

Comment: Increase your memory in php.ini file for your error. And why are you doing this or exporting in this way

Comment: @ShaileshSingh I've tried that in the past. It's not a viable solution as there is no amount of memory that will allow this to work. No matter how large I set the limit it is always reached.

Comment: I no longer get the error about reaching the memory limit. I think it was just a fluke that it showed up in the first place.

Comment: No, you cannot export on the client using server side since you do not have all the rows.   Exporting on the server is easy, just create a CSV file and d'load and excel can open it

Comment: @ChrisCaviness I cannot use CVS, I need to add formatting to the files as they are created and CVS does not allow this. Also I am able to pull the data that I need in the second attempt that I made above, I just don't know how to send that to the file I have that will create the Excel File using PHPExcel.

Comment: Just use the answer from here.
Works like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335685/4476745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this working, mostly. It is now timing out, but that's a separate issue due to data size not to this working. For small datasets, it works perfectly.

This is how I create the button (it's the *export* button that I'm using here):

```
"buttons": [{
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Selection',
                buttons: ['selectAll', 'selectNone']
            }, {
                extend: 'collection',
                text: 'Export',
                buttons: ['export', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'Export Current Page',
                    exportOptions: {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    },
                    customize: function (xlsx)
                    {
                        var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                        $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
                    }
                }]
            }
            ]
```

This is the initialization of the button created above:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',
    id: 'ExportButton',
    text: "Export All Test III",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        var SearchData = dt.rows({ filter: 'applied' }).data();
        var SearchData1 = dt.search();
        console.log(SearchData);
        var OrderData = dt.order();
        console.log(SearchData1);
        var NumCol = SearchData[0].length;
        var NumRow = SearchData.length;
        var SearchData2 = [];
        for (j = 0; j < NumRow; j++)
        {
            var NewSearchData = SearchData[j];
            for (i = 0; i < NewSearchData.length; i++)
            {
                NewSearchData[i] = NewSearchData[i].replace("<div class='Scrollable'>", "");
                NewSearchData[i] = NewSearchData[i].replace("</div>", "");
            }
            SearchData2.push([NewSearchData]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < SearchData2.length; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < SearchData2[i].length; j++)
            {
                SearchData2[i][j] = SearchData2[i][j].join('::');
            }
        }
        SearchData2 = SearchData2.join("%%");
        window.location.href = './ServerSide.php?ExportToExcel=Yes';
    }
};
```

And here is the part of the *ServerSide.php* file that gets the data and sends it to the server for processing:

```
require('FilterSort.class.php');

if (isset($_GET['ExportToExcel']) && $_GET['ExportToExcel'] == 'Yes')
{
    $request = @unserialize($_COOKIE['KeepPost']);
    $DataReturn = json_encode(FilterSort::complex($request,$sqlConnect,$table,$primaryKey,$ColumnHeader));
    require './ExportAllToExcel.php';
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(FilterSort::complex($request,$sqlConnect,$table,$primaryKey,$ColumnHeader));
}
```

This is how I set the cookie that I use to keep the search and sort criteria:

```
if(isset($_POST['draw']))
{
    $KeepPost = $_POST;    
    $KeepPost['length'] = -1;
    $PostKept = serialize($KeepPost);
    setcookie("KeepPost",$PostKept,time() + (60*60*24*7));
}
```

All this combined sends the correct criteria to *FilterSort.class.php* which should process the criteria and return the dataset to *ExportAllToExcell.php* which then creates the Excel file. Right now I'm sending it huge reports and it times out, though.

**UPDATE**

I have slightly changed the way that I do this:

Here is the new set of buttons:

```
"buttons": [{
    extend: 'collection',
    text: 'Export',
    buttons: ['export', { extend: 'csv',
        text: 'Export All To CSV',              //Export all to CSV file
        action: function (e, dt, node, config)
        {
            window.location.href = './ServerSide.php?ExportToCSV=Yes';
        }
    }, 'csv', 'pdf', { extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export Current Page',            //Export to Excel only the current page and highlight the first row as headers
        exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
                page: 'current'
            }
        },
        customize: function (xlsx)
        {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
            $('row:first c', sheet).attr('s', '7');
        }
    }]
}
]
```

Here is how I create the *Export All to Excel* button:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.export =
{
    className: 'buttons-alert',                         //Adds the "Export all to Excel" button
    id: 'ExportButton',
    text: "Export All To Excel",
    action: function (e, dt, node, config)
    {
        window.location.href = './ServerSide.php?ExportToExcel=Yes';
    }
};
```

These now send the data to the same *ServerSide.php* file that I was using before:

```
require('FilterSort.class.php');
if (isset($_GET['ExportToExcel']) && $_GET['ExportToExcel'] == 'Yes')
{
    include 'Helper/LogReport.php';
    $GetSQL = "Select Value from PostKept where UserName = '" .$_COOKIE['UserName']. "'";
    $KeepResult = $conn->query($GetSQL);
    $KeepResults = $KeepResult->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $request = unserialize($KeepResults[0]['Value']);

    $DataReturn = json_encode(FilterSort::complex($request,$sqlConnect,$table,$primaryKey,$ColumnHeader,1));
    require './ExportAllToExcel.php';
```

I have also changed the way that I keep the query, I have it now also keeping the *Table Name* and *UserName* like this:

```
include 'DBConn.php';
$KeepPost = $_POST;                                     //POST holds all the data for the search
$KeepPost['length'] = -1;                               //-1 means pulling the whole table
$PostKept = serialize($KeepPost);                       //This takes the array of data and turns it into a string for storage in SQL
$SQLCheck = "select distinct UserName from PostKept";   //Gets all the distinct Usernames of users that have used the Report Dashboard.
$sth = $conn->query($SQLCheck);
$CheckedUser = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($CheckedUser as $User)
{
    foreach($User as $Index => $Who)
    {
        $FoundUsers[] = $Who;                           //Taking all the found users and placing them into a simpler array for searching later

    }
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['UserName']) && in_array($_COOKIE['UserName'],$FoundUsers))   //If the user already has an entry update it with new information
{
    $TSQL = "UPDATE PostKept set Value = '" .$PostKept. "', TableName = '" .$TableName. "' where UserName = '" .$_COOKIE['UserName']. "'";
}
else
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['UserName']))     //If this is a new user
    {
        $TSQL = "INSERT into PostKept(Value, TableName, UserName) select '" .$PostKept. "','" .$TableName. "','" .$_COOKIE['UserName']. "'";
    }
    else        //If this is on the Prod site and the User info is not yet kept
    {
        $TSQL = "INSERT into PostKept(Value, TableName) select '" .$PostKept. "','" .$TableName. "'";
    }
}

$sth = $conn->prepare($TSQL);
$sth->execute();
```

This is now what all combines to send the data to the *ExportAllToExcel.php* file that I have and then it in turn creates the file.

Answer (score 22):

### First add the follwoing code in DataTable

```
"dom": 'Blfrtip',
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "extend": 'excel',
                            "text": '<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" style="color: green;"></i>  Excel</button>',
                            "titleAttr": 'Excel',
                            "action": newexportaction
                        },
                    ],
```

### Then add this function inside $(document).ready() function

```
function newexportaction(e, dt, button, config) {
         var self = this;
         var oldStart = dt.settings()[0]._iDisplayStart;
         dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
             // Just this once, load all data from the server...
             data.start = 0;
             data.length = 2147483647;
             dt.one('preDraw', function (e, settings) {
                 // Call the original action function
                 if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-copy') >= 0) {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.copyHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                 } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-excel') >= 0) {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                 } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-csv') >= 0) {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.csvFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                 } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-pdf') >= 0) {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                 } else if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-print') >= 0) {
                     $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.print.action(e, dt, button, config);
                 }
                 dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
                     // DataTables thinks the first item displayed is index 0, but we're not drawing that.
                     // Set the property to what it was before exporting.
                     settings._iDisplayStart = oldStart;
                     data.start = oldStart;
                 });
                 // Reload the grid with the original page. Otherwise, API functions like table.cell(this) don't work properly.
                 setTimeout(dt.ajax.reload, 0);
                 // Prevent rendering of the full data to the DOM
                 return false;
             });
         });
         // Requery the server with the new one-time export settings
         dt.ajax.reload();
     }
```

Comment: This worked for me. You can use data.length = -1 instead of data.length = 2147483647;

Comment: It works, but no guarantee that you won't eventually run into an OOME as your table grows in size or if server resources are reduced unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this and came up with an alternate solution.

In the DataTable options, add this:

```
"lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
```

This will allow user to select all rows and will send -1 to server in 'length' query string parameter. At server side, you need to handle negative number and allow to return all rows when -1 is received.

This would display all rows in table and will export all of them.

I understand that this may not be suitable for 50-60K rows but for a smaller dataset, this can work without implementing any additional code at server and client side both.

Comment: You are correct that this would work for small data sets, however, this particular data set can be more than 100K rows so printing that to the screen would take >5min which is not acceptable. I do already have this in the menu though as it allows the user to select what they see. It seems to work well when less than 1K rows, but then I have close to 200 columns per row so it might work well with smaller data sets with higher row count but lower column count. This also does not answer my question of printing everything from the first page and not needing to show all in order to print all.

Comment: Ok Mike. Got your point. I just posted the answer in case someone end up here and have the same problem with less number of rows/columns.

Comment: the most simple solution

Answer (score 1):

in buttons:

```
action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

var formData = 'yourfilters';
formData.begin = '0';
formData.length = 'yourTotalSize';

$http({
    url: 'yourURL',
    method: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(formData)
}).then(function (ajaxReturnedData) {

    dt.rows.add(ajaxReturnedData.data).draw();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, node, config);

});}
```