# Datatables export option to csv is not fetching all data

Tags: datatables

I have used datatable to view 500K table data and used server processing option since the data table is huge,

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#employee_grid').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "server_processing.php",
            "dom": 'lBfrtip',
            "buttons": [
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy',
                        'excel',
                        'csv',
                        'pdf',
                        'print'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Am trying now to use the export option but what am getting is the first 10 records only...
how can I change it so I export all filtered data and not the data shown in the first page only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#Server-side-processing) there is no way to export all rows when you are using server side.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33301613/7456905) on the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables's default behavior can be overridden, and relying on the length option is not sufficient for large data sets, in my experience. See a better SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44635032).