# Making multiple ajax calls with DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

**Background :**

There is a dataTables implementation which supports all the basic feature like sorting based on a column, exporting the table to excel sheet etc.

We use a API in order to fetch the data and feed the response object to the dataTables. Currently we have around 100000 records in the database and it might increase.

**Limitation :**

The API which we use has a limitation that it will return only 1000 results at once. It has given the flexibility to make use of top and skip parameters.

The API sends basic information like count which sends total number of records.

**Requirement :**

The requirement is to display all the results and also while exporting the data, entire data should be available in the excel sheet.

**My implementation :**

I am making multiples ajax calls.

- With the 1st ajax call, I am able to determine the count of total records
- From 2nd onward I am using the count variable for looping and making multiple ajax call. For each success ajax call I am concatenating the response in a object.

Once all the ajax calls are successful, I am sending the object to DataTables.

**Issue :**

The above described implementation takes 4-5 mins to load.Also the same time is consumed when the export functionality(converting to excel sheet) is executed.

---

Please suggest a good approach which I can implement in order to achieve all the functionalities.

Comment: Can you Provide more information like which api you are currently using. and display some code, how you are doing that?

Comment: check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33301613/5813861), it may help you to understand server side export functionality.

Comment: Thanks Yash. Its a azure API which the other team has restricted to 1000 records at a time.
What I am looking for is if all the API calls can go in parallel and if it can be successful within 1 min.

Comment: Hi @Pallavi Sripada, I did not get your issue. You are using server side api to load 1000 data at a time, but you want to display all 1,00,000 data directly into datatable using client side.. right?

Comment: Are you saying you have 10 000 000 000 records now? Please don't use Indian words like "lakh".

Comment: @JamesZ : Oops ! I corrected it. Its 100000 records for now.

Comment: @yash : Yes I was trying to achieve it using client side which lead to browser crash.

Comment: @Pallavi Sripada, add screenshot and explain what is happening and what you want.