# How to export additional fields/columns to CSV / Excel in Jquery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the Jquery datatable plugin to load a student list from a json file as shown below :

student.html

```
<table class="table" id="student-grid" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-header">
            <th>Reg No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

student.js

```
var dt = $("#student-grid").DataTable({
        "scrollY": "400px","scrollCollapse":true,"paging":false,"bSortCellsTop": true, "autoWidth": false,          
        "ajax": cntxt_root + "data/student.json",
        data: [], 
        "columns": [
            {"data" : "regNo", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data" : "name", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data" : "gender", "defaultContent": ""},
            {"data" : "grade", "defaultContent": ""}
        ]
        });
```

I have added below code to export student list to CSV/Excel

```
//export buttons for student table
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( dt, {
    buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                filename:'StudentList',
                exportOptions:{ orthogonal : 'export'}
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                filename:'StudentList'
            }
        ]
    });

    dt.buttons( 0, null ).container().prependTo(
        dt.table().container()
    );
```

There are few other student details like address, marks in student.json file which I don't want to display in the datatable but want these fields -address & marks to be exported to CSV & Excel.

1) How to export these additional fields that are not added/available in the datatable ? 
2) How to add - address & marks columns in addition to existing columns in datatable to CSV/Excel in **buttons.exportData()** function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export all rows from Datatables using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692618/how-to-export-all-rows-from-datatables-using-ajax)

Comment: I think the link shared doesn't explain on how to add new columns other than ones available in the datatable to the excel/csv export if I am not wrong.